# How to combine different azimuth hillshades (e.g 45°,315°) extracted from the same DEM using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, hillshade

I've a DEM from which I created duplicates that have different azimuthal values on hillshades. I would like to see the possibility of combining different azimuths (e.g 0°, 45° and 315°) in a single raster (It's not the multi-directional function).

Comment: Sorry, I don't get, what your final result should look like. Can you provide an example?

Comment: Sure, in this Fig (pag 5 and 6) combine multiple azimuth hillshade in one. The paper suggests combining with SAGA mosaic raster layer , but only exists function mosaicking and the results are different.

https://revistasinvestigacion.unmsm.edu.pe/index.php/iigeo/article/view/20414/17512

Comment: Using layer blending modes solves your problem?